# GDAL understanding multiple EPSG codes for a single GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdalinfo

What does multiple EPSG codes for a single raster image mean ? Is it that the extent spanning across different projection zones.If so how can one generate it using GDAL when an unprojected/GCS image is projected.

```
C:\Data>gdalinfo MyImage.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: MyImage.tif
Size is 17932, 12384
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["Lambert Conformal Conic",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4269]],
    CONVERSION["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
        METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
            ID["EPSG",9802]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",42.166666666666,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-89,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",46.6666666666667,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",41.3333333333333,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-411299.273570650490001,269487.460171752958558)
Pixel Size = (42.335081965870593,-42.336080785207301)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2020:03:18 07:47:30
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CC (Windows)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=300
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=300
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -411299.274,  269487.460) ( 94d10'42.78"W, 44d28'41.48"N)
Lower Left  ( -411299.274, -254802.564) ( 93d47'42.39"W, 39d45'55.59"N)
Upper Right (  347853.416,  269487.460) ( 84d37' 7.10"W, 44d30'40.70"N)
Lower Right (  347853.416, -254802.564) ( 84d56'35.77"W, 39d47'45.79"N)
Center      (  -31722.929,    7342.448) ( 89d23' 4.29"W, 42d13'55.71"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are EPSG codes for different types, like

- Coordinate Transformation
- Coordinate Reference System
- Coordinate Conversion
- Datum
- Ellipsoid
- Coordinate Operation Method
- Coordinate System
- Axis Name
- Unit of Measure (UOM)
- Area of Use

In your WKT the IDs with EPSG code mean different things. For example ID["EPSG",9001] as a lengthunit means metre http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?gml=urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9001

It seems that this coordinate system WKT is actually missing the EPSG code for the Projected CRS. That does not matter, the CRS is totally defined with the other parameters and GDAL and the Proj library know what to do.